# Confusing Javascript quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the jQuery docs mostly every string is "declared" using single quotes. Including the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) for jQuery UI.

So why doesn't this

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy' });
```

work, but this

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy" });
```

does? When using single quotes, the datepicker ignores my `dateFormat` setting.

(Ignore my silly habit of using double-quotes in the jQuery selector, but single quotes everywhere else :P )

Comment: strange, i just checked in my current project and i use single quotes and it works. which versions of jQuery / jQueryUI are you using?

Comment: Where does that line of code live? in a separate javascript file? in a script tag? in an onclick attribute? Most importantly, is it inside a string which is delimited by single quotes?

Comment: It lives inside a javascript file, and is wrapped in jQuery's ready function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm.. Maybe [here](http://simonwillison.net/2006/oct/11/json/) is the answer. But, anyway, I still can't understand why you have an error here.

Comment: That's probably it. Because when I use the "correct" json according to that page, it work's with single quotes...

Comment: Your example isn't JSON. JSON is just a strict subset of Javascript's object literals; it can be used to store and transmit data across platforms, languages, and browsers. This is not the correct answer unless you are parsing an object-literal *string* as JSON before passing it off to datepicker.

Comment: Ok. So if this isn't the answer, what is? Because this worked. So I'm keeping this as the correct answer for now, since it actually did help me.

Answer (score 2):

They're identical. Javascript can use single or double qotes for string literals.

Therefore, you must have an error elsewhere that is causing you a problem. Try to distill a test page down to the bare minimum to try to ascertain where this error could be.

Comment: But when I use single quotes around the format, the datepicker ignores the setting... Maybe I should point that out :/

Comment: which totally doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @jAndy - It totally does answer the question - just not in the way that the OP might have hoped. Implicitly, the answer is that the OP must have an error elsewhere, but perhaps I should have been more *explicit* with that assertion.

Comment: I also did downvote, because after I edited the question, it _doesn't_ answer the question. I see, however, that it could have done that before my edit.

Comment: @Jamiec:No downvoting here. It's a pretty big assumption tho that you stated. The answer looks like, "the moon is in earths orbit" which implicitly means that the error is on earth.

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is impossible.
Javascript has no way of knowing if single or double quotes are being used in an object literal (`{string: "string"}`); and even if it did, datepicker and jQuery(UI) doesn't care.

Now, if you are receiving the object-literal as a JSON object via XMLHttpRequest (or just parsing the an object-literal as JSON) single quotes will fail, though so will unquoted names in the name/value pair like you have in your example.

The only other thing I can think of that would cause this problem is if you are using backticks (`) or curly quotes instead of single quotes (`‘’`).